# Get List of Previous in a Table and Sum Days

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Get List Of Previous Years**

I am creating a leave management system.I have to get the list of previous years of an employee from a table and sum the days if there is any. If there is no previous years, then I have to pick the days in the current year. The FindEmployee method returns a list of employee with his data and dates in the leave table.

This is the leave model

```
public class LeaveTable
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Leave Leave { get; set; }
    public string LeaveCode { get; set; }
    public int Days { get; set; }
    public int Balance { get; set; }
    public int UsedDays { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
public async Task<decimal> CheckEmployeeOutstandingBalance(string employeeId)
        {
            var employees = FindEmployee(employeeId).Result.ToList();
            var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
            var previousYear = currentYear - 1;
            var days = 0;

            if(previousYear != 0)
             days = employees.Sum(s => s.Balance);



            foreach (var employee in employees)
            {

                if (previousYear != 0)
                {
                    days = employee
                }
            }



            //return await Task.FromResult(employees);
        }
```

Any suggestions to get the list of previous years and sum the days if there is any.

Comment: Exactly what point are you facing the issue?

Comment: I feel the code I have isn't correct. I need suggestion of how to get the list of previous dates from the current dates because the table can have a list of 2016,2017 and 2018 and they will also have days respectively

Comment: @lutakyn, you need to get sum of days or sum of balance?

Comment: @lutakyn, plz add your `Employee`  entity also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the code and this works.

```
  public async Task<decimal> CheckEmployeeOutstandingBalance(string employeeId)
            {
                var employee = FindEmployee(employeeId).Result.ToList();//returns list of employees
                var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
                var balanceSum = 0;
                var results = 0;
                var currentBalance = 0;
                var prev = employee.Where(s => s.Year != currentYear).ToList();
                var currentyear = employee.Where(s => s.Year == currentYear).FirstOrDefault();
                 currentBalance = currentyear.Balance;
                balanceSum = prev.Sum(s => s.Balance);

                 results = balanceSum + currentBalance;
                return await Task.FromResult(results);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(previousYear != 0)
       days = employees.Sum(s => s.Balance);
  else
    {
     days = LeaveTable.Where(l => l.Year <currentYear && l.EmployeeId == employeeId ).Sum( li => li.Balance)
    }
```